# Javascript change label color in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of `labels` I created on a php page, they all have an id like

- `<label id="1_p">`
- `<label id="2_p">`
- `<label id="3_p">`
- `<label id="4_p">`
- `<label id="5_p">`...

I have to change their color to `#D8D8D8` and I thought to do it using a for loop:

```
for(i=1;i<13;++i) {
 document.getElementById(i+'_p').style.color='#D8D8D8';
}
```

By the way Firefox tells me that document.getElementById(...) is null. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think it's because you're trying to add a number with a string `'_p'`. Try `document.getElementById(i.toString()+'_p').style.color='#D8D8D8';`

Comment: it is the same as i.toString(); ?

Comment: Can I suggest you to use Jquery instead?

Comment: @ElliotM — No, `1 + "x"` is `"1x"`. Numbers are stringified automatically when you try to add a string to them.

Comment: @Alberto Rossi Specify a class for coloring multiple tags with common characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/nKuJw/

```
 for(var i=1;i<6;i++) {
   document.getElementById(i+'_p').style.color='#D8D8D8';
 }
```

Notice I'm using `i++` and not `++i`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't start id value by number / it's breach of HTML specification

Have a look at this answer: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Do you mean 'breach' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. It's fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to all of the labels like

```
<label id="5_p" class="colorOrSomething">
```

then instead you can use the class to look them all up and change the color

```
document.getElementsByClassName('colorOrSomething')
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `int` with `string` should work. Make sure you have specified `i` as `var`.

As an alternative to `javascript` you could use [CSS3 Attribute Selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors)

```
label[id*='_p'] {color:#D8D8D8 }
```

#### Addendum

Class identifiers are allowed to start with a number, but ID identifiers are not.

```
[id='1_p'] {
 /* does work */
}

#1_p {
  /* doesn't work */
}
```

[source](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)